# Extending histogram function to overlapping bins and bins with arbitrary gap?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a histogram function that handles any general bins?

In my neuroscience application, I have two 1D arrays: `spikes` and `time_centers` and a  parameter `time_window`. My goal is to output array called `firing_rate` that has the same size as `time_centers`, defined as `firing_rate[i]=len(abs(spikes-time_centers[i])<time_window)`, so that it counts the number of spikes near each `time_center` bin in the interval of width `time_window`.

I quickly drafted a function, but I am a little concerned with a performance, as I need to process a very large number of spike sequences.

```
def fr(spikes,time_bins,time_window):
    rate=np.zeros(time_bins.size)
    for i,t in enumerate(time_bins):
        rate[i]= sum(np.abs(spikes-t)<time_window)
    return rate
```

Is it possible to take advantage of the fact that `spikes` array is sorted?
Even though I work with the bins of the same size (`time_window`), my bins can overlap, or there can be a variable gap between the bins.

Typically `spikes` contain ~ 1000 elements, `time_centers` ~ 50 bins and I need to calculate it for 30000 neurons per session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the sorted nature with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
idx1 = np.searchsorted(spikes,time_bins-time_window,'right')
idx2 = np.searchsorted(spikes,time_bins+time_window,'left')
rate = idx2-idx1
```

Alternatively, with one `searchsorted` for `time_bins` being within the limits of `spikes` -

```
T = np.r_[time_bins-time_window,time_bins+time_window]
n = len(time_bins)
idxx = np.searchsorted(spikes,T,'left')
idx1 = idxx[:n] + (time_bins-spikes[idxx[:n]]>=time_window)
idx2 = idxx[n:]
```

Comment: @MikhailGenkin Check out the alternative one with one searchsorted. Should be better on your use-case with smaller time_bins array.

Comment: thanks! First method is 1000 faster than my draft with for loops. Your second method appears to be two times slower than the first one

Comment: great and fast, the fist method (two searchsorted) is the fastest that I've found so far

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of broadcasting:

```py
def fr(spikes, time_bins, time_window):
    spikes = spikes.reshape((-1, 1))
    time_bins = time_bins.reshape((1, -1))
    rate = np.sum(np.abs(spikes - time_bins) < time_window, axis=0)
    return rate
```

Comment: Thanks, also a very fast way and transparent way to do it

Comment: This is a great idea to use numpy reshaped arrays to get the correct combinations, but the downside is that it is very memory consuming ... cannot allocate 180 GiB ;) that's a shortcoming